# Remove Header from DotPeek files

Tags: dotpeek

I am trying to diff two versions of an application via decompiling them with DotPeek and then running a compare between them.  But each file adds a header like this to the top:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Common.ODataList`1
// Assembly: Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: 11D70360-276E-4C80-B7DB-EA9D9A52D841
// Assembly location: E:\src\Scratch\ShiptrackCompare\prodDlls\Common.dll
```

The MVID is different for each file, so my diffs always show a difference for each file.

**Is there a way to get DotPeek to not add this header?**

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is an XY-problem. What you really want is to ignore the MVID in the comparison.

Configure your difftool to ignore comments. E.g. in Winmerge, select the Prediffer to ignore comments.

[image: Winmerge ignore comments]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dotPeek, you can use [dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy). It will not emit such a header in decompiled code.

You might want to turn off "Show tokens, RVA and file offsets" in the options to improve comparison.